# display category title in django listview

Tags: django, class, listview, categories, title

Wish to display category title in each blog category index page, using django class based listview. What I want to do is to show each category.title in each selected category page. But nothing is shown. Below is the model, view, template and it must be something small I am missing.

```
# models.py
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100,)  
    slug = models.SlugField(_('url'), max_length=250, unique=True)
    summary = models.TextField(_('summary'), max_length=255)   

class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category))
    title = models.CharField(_('title'), max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(_('url'), max_length=250, unique=True)
    content= models.TextField(_('summary'), null=True)

# view.py
class PostCategoryMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(PostCategoryMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['category'] = Category.objects.filter(is_public=True)
        return context        

class PostList(PostCategoryMixin, ListView):  
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(is_public=True)
    template_name = 'post/post_list.html' 

class PostCategoryView(BlogCategoryMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'post/post_list.html' 
    model = Post
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(category__slug=self.kwargs.get('slug')).filter(is_public=True) 

# post_list.html
{{ category_title }}
```

Above template tag does not fire any at all, what do I look into to display category title in the selected category page (ex, if 'software' category is selected, I wish to show 'software' as the page title.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong here, but the most obvious is that you don't have a variable called `category_view` in your context, so it's not surprising that trying to print it outputs nothing.

What you do have is a variable called `category` which (confusingly) is actually a list of categories. You'll have to iterate through that list and print the title of each one:

```
{% for cat in category %}
    {{ cat.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

(although you should probably rename the variable to 'categories').

**Edit** Once again, it's not so much that you're missing something small, but that you're just not doing the things you need to do in order to get the result you want. If you want to print out a specific category, then you need somewhere to fetch that category from the database, and you're simply not doing that.

You could replace your categories query with a more specific one, and use `get` instead of `filter`:

```
context['category'] = Category.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['slug'], is_public=True)
```

but note that this won't work in the PostList view, which for some reason is sharing the same template, as that view has no slug kwarg.

Comment: Yes, that does print out the categories - all categories in sequence. To that extent, things are easy but the thing is that when I click (ex, 'Photo' category), I wish to show the 'Photo' as the category title - <h1>Photo</h1>. What should I be looking into, guess it is to do with views.py that I am missing something small.

Comment: All the posts in each category is all fetched good... it is just that I wish to print out 'category.title' in each respective category of blog post, like {{ category.title }} in the post_list.html template. Category has 'title, slug, summary, is_public' fields. Still valid that I perhaps should do views all again?